# 'MultipleErrorsOccurred' error message display when i am trying to move Resource Group to another subscription

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-resource-group

I am trying to move the Resource group from one subscription to another subscription. My Resource group only contains the SQL Server and SQL databases.

**Note: Script working fine for Resource group which do not have SQL server or databases.**

I am able to do that manually from the Azure portal but when I tried Powershell it gives the error message.

**Powershell:**

```
$subscriptionID = "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"
$destinationSubscriptionID = "YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY"
Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionID -TenantId $tenant | Set-AzContext
$RG = "condecoteam2ent"
$Resource = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $RG
Write-host "ResourceIds : " $Resource.ResourceId
Move-AzResource -ResourceId $Resource.ResourceId -DestinationSubscriptionId $destinationSubscriptionID -DestinationResourceGroupName $RG -Force
```

**Error:**

```
ResourceIds :  /subscriptions/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/resourceGroups/condecoteam2ent/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/qateam2server /subscriptions/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/resourceGroups/condecoteam2ent/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/qateam2server/databases/master /subscriptions/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/resourceGroups/condecoteam2ent/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/qateam2server/databases/entmobiledb /subscriptions/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/resourceGroups/condecoteam2ent/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/qateam2server/databases/minsyncdb /subscriptions/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/resourceGroups/condecoteam2ent/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/qateam2server/databases/conintdb /subscriptions/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/resourceGroups/condecoteam2ent/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/qateam2server/databases/minisyncload /subscriptions/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/resourceGroups/condecoteam2ent/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/qateam2server/databases/conintdb_Copy /subscriptions/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/resourceGroups/condecoteam2ent/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/qateam2server/databases/condecosyncqa3

MultipleErrorsOccurred : Multiple error occurred: BadRequest,BadRequest,BadReque
st,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest. Please see details.
CorrelationId: c02ad7c5-5b92-41b7-9d77-bce0261ed2a5
```

**Debug logs:**

```
{
        "code": "ResourceNotTopLevel",
        "message": "Identifier '/subscriptions/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/resourceGroups/condecoteam2ent/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/qateam2server
/databases/minisyncload' is not a top level resource. Please include only the to
p-level resource for this child resource in the move request. A child resource w
ould be moved along with its associated top-level resource.\""
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I am able to resolve it.

First of all, the script only failed while moving Resource Group which has SQL server and databases.

After investigation, I found that we do not need to move each database of the SQL server. We only need to move top-level resource of the Resource group (i.e SQL Server) and its databases will move automatically with it.

So now I need to exclude the resource ids of the database type I am fetching from Resource Group.

```
$Resource = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $RG | Where-Object {$_.ResourceType -notcontains "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases"}
```

Now onwards I am getting all the resource id except databases. So now I am able to move any type of Resource Group irrespective of its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can move resources to another resource group

To move existing resources to another resource group or subscription, use the `Move-AzureRmResource` command.

Below is the command for moving one resource to new subscription

````
    ```
PS C:\> $resource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceName ExampleApp -ResourceGroupName OldRG
PS C:\> Move-AzureRmResource -DestinationResourceGroupName NewRG -ResourceId $resource.ResourceId
```
````

For multiple resources to new subscription

````
```
PS C:\> $webapp = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName OldRG -ResourceName ExampleSite
PS C:\> $plan = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName OldRG -ResourceName ExamplePlan
PS C:\> Move-AzureRmResource -DestinationResourceGroupName NewRG -ResourceId ($webapp.ResourceId, $plan.ResourceId)
```
````

You can even [Refer](https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/resource-group-move-resources.md#:%7E:text=Using%20PowerShell%20to%20move%20resources,-%5BAZURE.INCLUDE%20powershell&text=To%20move%20existing%20resources%20to,use%20the%20Move-AzureRmResource%20command.) for more details

Comment: Sorry I cannot use AzureRmResource as AzureRM PowerShell modules will be deprecated in future.